# How can I shuffle a list

Tags: list, unity-game-engine, coordinates, shuffle

this code is for a game I create in unity. I have a list with 100 elements of coordinates and I want to instantiate boxes to them. The Amount of boxes should be 50% and totaly random. If I run my script, I get 50% of the boxes but in the default order. My script don't shuffle the elements in the list. Thanks for help!

```
 // List has 100 elements of coordinates ( x & y)
 public List<Vector2> ListPosBoxes = new List<Vector2>(); 

 // Start   
 void Start()
 {
     AmountOfBoxes(ListPosBoxes);
 }

 // Method to display 50% shuffled boxes    
 void AmountOfBoxes(List<Vector2> list)
 {
     // Take list -> shuffle -> new list
     list = ShuffleList(list);

     for (int i = 0; i < list.Count/2; i++)
         {
         // Create Box
             BoxGenerator(list[i]);
         }
 }

 // Method to suffle list
 List<Vector2> ShuffleList(List<Vector2> list)
 {
     Vector2 tmp;

     // fisher–yates shuffle
         for (int i = list.Count; i < 1; i--)
         {
             // Pick random Element
             int j = Random.Range(0, list.Count);

             // Swap Elements
             tmp = list[j];
             list[j] = list[i - 1];
             list[i - 1] = tmp;
         }
     return list;
 }

 // Method to create Box
 void BoxGenerator(Vector2 box) 
 {
         CreateBox(box.x, box.y);
 }
```

**The problem is: the list isn't mixed.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running your for-loop from high numbers and decrease i.

```
// fisher–yates shuffle
     for (int i = list.Count; i < 1; i--)
```

But the test in the for loop is `i smaller than 1` so it never runs. Place a `Debug.Log` in the for-loop to test and flip the operator

Comment: I also just noticed. Embarrassing! Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are trying to re-declare a parameter.

For more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters

Perhaps start with:

```
 void AmountOfBoxes(List<Vector2> list)
 {
     // Take list -> shuffle -> new list
     shuffled_list = ShuffleList(list);

     for (int i = 0; i < list.Count/2; i++)
         {
         // Create Box
             BoxGenerator(shuffled_list[i]);
         }
 }

// Method to suffle list
 List<Vector2> ShuffleList(List<Vector2> list)
 {
     Vector2 tmp;
     list *= list;

     // fisher–yates shuffle
         for (int i = list.Count; i < 1; i--)
         {
             // Pick random Element
             int j = Random.Range(0, list.Count);

             // Swap Elements
             tmp = list[j];
             list[j] = list[i - 1];
             list[i - 1] = tmp;
         }
     return list;
 }
```

I hope this helps.

What could also help you with debugging, is logging your variables someplace so that you know where it went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your idea with the debugging. The problem is on this line: for (int i = list.Count; i < 1; i--) ---> i > 1 fix the problem. 
Embarrassing! :D

Comment: @Paski7 this is not true. The problem is not (just) the indexing but the fact that you're manipulating the same list instead of creating a new one. Check again

Comment: @asaf92 I checked my code and it work fine now with only one list. It works also finde with two lists. The Problem was the "<" because I'm decrease.

Comment: OK, as long as you don't want to shuffle the ListPosBoxes property it should be fine, but the `list = ShuffleList(list)` part was suspicious

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of mistakes actually as mentioned in the previous answers but first of all, that `Random.Range(0, list.Count);` is quite biased actually, please check [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Implementation_errors) to have a better understanding of why.

And here is the corrected code:

```
// fisher–yates shuffle     
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {

     // Pick random Element
     int j = Random.Range(i, list.Count);

     // Swap Elements
     Vector2 tmp = list[i];
     list[i] = list[j];
     list[j] = tmp;
}
```